# Does TFF support deployment across different devices and clouds?

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I would like to deploy TFF in a way, where I have one central (aggregation) server on a VM in a cloud and two different VMs with nodes, that train the model. Is this possible with TFF? Does it have the protocols necessary to communicate over the internet etc. or is it more of a Tensorflow with FL algorithms that can be used with different frameworks that provide the architecture?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can run TFF simulations on GCP: https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/gcp_setup

Comment: TFF simulations, however, can I deploy it in a manner I explained and let nodes communicate over the internet?

Comment: The tutorial for multiple machine simulations on GCP will be available at https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/simulations